# java Duration, time returning null distancematrix.api

Tags: java, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I getting confused with how to get duration, time and distance traveled using google distancematrix.api I can't understand whats not working with my code, all that I'm getting are null values. why ?? Below is my javacode

```
         DistanceMatrix results1 =  DistanceMatrixApi.getDistanceMatrix(context, 
                new String[] {"rose hill"}, new String[] {"port louis"}).units(Unit.METRIC).await();

    System.out.println(results1.rows[0].elements[0].duration);
    System.out.println(results1.rows[0].elements[0].distance);
    System.out.println(results1.rows[0].elements[0].distance);
```

context as requested

```
        GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
.apiKey("AIzaSyC..")
.build();
```

Comment: What is your `context`? Please show us the builder.

Comment: @Blake edited, please see post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me just by creating (and enabling) an API key on the google maps

Here is my code

```
public class GoogleDistance {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {
        new GoogleDistance().go();
    }

    void go() throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {
        String API_KEY = "AIzy....";
        GeoApiContext.Builder builder = new GeoApiContext.Builder();
        builder.apiKey(API_KEY);

        GeoApiContext geoApiContext = builder.build();
        DistanceMatrix results1 = DistanceMatrixApi.getDistanceMatrix(geoApiContext,
                new String[]{"rose hill"}, new String[]{"port louis"}).units(Unit.METRIC).await();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results1.destinationAddresses));
    }
}
```

I believe the issue may be with your prints: I don't think you should be doing `rows[0].elements[0]` just use Arrays.toString().

When I run my code it outputs `[Port Louis, Mauritius]`

*EDIT*

I think I now see what you were trying to do. Please take a look at the following

```
public class GoogleDistance {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {
        new GoogleDistance().go();
    }

    void go() throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {
        String API_KEY = "AIzy...";
        GeoApiContext.Builder builder = new GeoApiContext.Builder();
        builder.apiKey(API_KEY);

        GeoApiContext geoApiContext = builder.build();
        DistanceMatrix results1 = DistanceMatrixApi.getDistanceMatrix(geoApiContext,
                new String[]{"los angeles"}, new String[]{"san francisco"}).units(Unit.METRIC).await();


        DistanceMatrixRow[] rows = results1.rows;
        for (DistanceMatrixRow row : rows) {
            DistanceMatrixElement[] elements = row.elements;
            for (DistanceMatrixElement element : elements) {
                Distance distance = element.distance;
                if(distance == null){
                    System.out.println("distance is null");
                    continue;
                }
                String dist = distance.humanReadable;
                String dur = element.duration.humanReadable;
                System.out.println(dist);
                System.out.println(dur);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I believe you're getting null because google cant map between the locations you're providing.

Comment: ermm but its not giving me the duration :( thats not what i needed.. any help? :)